# How to arrange the order of join?

Tags: mysql, join

I need a table with 5 columns. X-C-D is a hierarchical relationship. A-B can be hierarchically related but not always so. X can have connections to A or B, sometimes directly to A or B, sometimes connected to A then related to B due to A-B can be connected.

1. col_A to col_B = One-to-Many relationship;
2. col_A to col_C = One-to-Many relationship;
3. col_B to col_C = One-to-Many relationship;
4. col_C to col_D = One-to-Many relationship;
5. col_X to col_A or col_B = One-to-Many relationship;
6. col_X to col_C = One-to-Many relationship;

Now I want to create a mysql View, list all records in col_D, and fill in A,B,C,or X when there's a match. Should the code start from A or D? and how to join X?

```
SELECT ....
     FROM table_A as a  ( or should I start from table_D ? )
LEFT JOIN table B as b  ( LEFT or INNER ?)
LEFT JOIN table C as c  ( LEFT or INNER ?)
LEFT JOIN table D as d  ( LEFT or INNER ?)
LEFT JOIN table X as x  ( or make a UNION with X ?)
```

Comment: Start with **D** because you said you _want all records in col D_. Then LEFT JOIN to the other tables. The relationship to X is difficult to understand. For any record in D, can you have many different X records due to the values in C, A and B? Sample data would help solve your problem

Comment: thanks. There are not many X, but X is the parent of C. If there is a D, there must be a C and a X. As for A and B, that's not in X-C-D hierarchy.